# Cypress - check selected item from combobox ng-selector

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to check if the selected item matches the desired text value. Now I choose value using position on the list, but the code for matching it isn't perfect. Do you have any recommendations?

```
  fillDivision(value) {
    cy.get('[formcontrolname="divisionId"]').click()
    cy.get('[class="ng-option-label"]')
      .eq(value)
      .click()
  }

  getDivision(value){
    cy.get('[role="combobox"]').contains.(value)
  }
```

HTML code

```
<ng-select _ngcontent-c7="" bindlabel="name" bindvalue="id" class="ng-select ng-select-single ng-select-searchable ng-select-bottom ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid ng-select-opened" formcontrolname="divisionId" role="listbox" ng-reflect-bind-label="name" ng-reflect-bind-value="id" ng-reflect-placeholder="Wybierz" ng-reflect-not-found-text="Brak" ng-reflect-select-on-tab="true" ng-reflect-items="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-name="divisionId"><div class="ng-select-container ng-has-value">
    <div class="ng-value-container">
        <div class="ng-placeholder">Choose item</div>

        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><!---->
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
}--><div class="ng-value">
                <!---->

                <!--bindings={


<div class="ng-input">
            <input role="combobox" type="text" autocomplete="a3645360b82a" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-expanded="true" aria-owns="a3645360b82a" aria-activedescendant="ae1ceb98bcb2">
        </div>


<div class="ng-option ng-option-selected" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="a84a6f75bcf1">

            <!---->

            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]",
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <span class="ng-option-label">Item_to_check</span>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of the `data-test` attribute. It's a great pattern to generate unique identifiers that makes testing a lot easier and more comprehensive. Read more about this [here](https://medium.com/@colecodes/test-your-dom-with-data-attributes-44fccc43ed4b).

Comment: Seems reasonable, however, I am not web dev and there is no possibility to change website code.

Comment: An alternative is to use `id`, which is supposed to be unique.

Comment: Any idea why I can't just use `cy.get('[class="ng-option-label"]')` when item contains `<span class="ng-option-label">Item_to_check</span>`?

Comment: As I just checked IDs are generated differently in every session - so this method here will not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I assume I can identify object by its `innerText` or `outerText` but Cypress does not allow to do that?

`Yielded:   (15) [div#ae295dfb0d66.ng-option, div#a73a9e1ddfb0.ng-option, div#acb834143a79.ng-option.ng-option-marked, div#aee4c4947524.ng-option, div#a7ce7a564daa.ng-option, div#a5afbfed816d.ng-option, div#ae097ef81dc2.ng-option, div#a48cdbf7f2da.ng-option, div#aa18d929cb28.ng-option, div#a90ccbee3869.ng-option, div#a90604682f2c.ng-option, div#ae68c651855a.ng-option, div#a82a56bd88d0.ng-option, div#a66361b792e6.ng-option, div#af5a67b311ae.ng-option]0: div#ae295dfb0d66.ng-option
accessKey: ""
align: ""
assignedSlot: null
attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 0}
attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: class, 1: role, 2: id, class: class, role: role, id: id, length: 3}
autocapitalize: ""
baseURI: "https://lab4.itcraft.pl:8282/"
childElementCount: 1
childNodes: NodeList(8) [text, comment, text, comment, text, span.ng-option-label, text, text]
children: HTMLCollection [span.ng-option-label]
classList: DOMTokenList ["ng-option", value: "ng-option"]
className: "ng-option"
clientHeight: 31
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 242
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap {}
dir: ""
draggable: false
firstChild: text
firstElementChild: span.ng-option-label
hidden: false
id: "ae295dfb0d66"
innerHTML: "↵↵            <!---->↵↵            <!--bindings={↵  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]",↵  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"↵}-->↵                <span class="ng-option-label">Gdańsk</span>↵            ↵        "
innerText: "Gdańsk"
inputMode: ""
isConnected: true
isContentEditable: false
lang: ""
lastChild: text
lastElementChild: span.ng-option-label
localName: "div"
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: div#a73a9e1ddfb0.ng-option
nextSibling: div#a73a9e1ddfb0.ng-option
nodeName: "DIV"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
nonce: ""
offsetHeight: 31
offsetLeft: 0
offsetParent: div.ng-dropdown-panel-items.scroll-host
offsetTop: 31
offsetWidth: 242
onabort: (...)
onauxclick: (...)
onbeforecopy: (...)
onbeforecut: (...)
onbeforepaste: (...)
onblur: (...)
oncancel: (...)
oncanplay: (...)
oncanplaythrough: (...)
onchange: (...)
onclick: (...)
onclose: (...)
oncontextmenu: (...)
oncopy: (...)
oncuechange: (...)
oncut: (...)
ondblclick: (...)
ondrag: (...)
ondragend: (...)
ondragenter: (...)
ondragleave: (...)
ondragover: (...)
ondragstart: (...)
ondrop: (...)
ondurationchange: (...)
onemptied: (...)
onended: (...)
onerror: (...)
onfocus: (...)
onfullscreenchange: (...)
onfullscreenerror: (...)
ongotpointercapture: (...)
oninput: (...)
oninvalid: (...)
onkeydown: (...)
onkeypress: (...)
onkeyup: (...)
onload: (...)
onloadeddata: (...)
onloadedmetadata: (...)
onloadstart: (...)
onlostpointercapture: (...)
onmousedown: (...)
onmouseenter: (...)
onmouseleave: (...)
onmousemove: (...)
onmouseout: (...)
onmouseover: (...)
onmouseup: (...)
onmousewheel: (...)
onpaste: (...)
onpause: (...)
onplay: (...)
onplaying: (...)
onpointercancel: (...)
onpointerdown: (...)
onpointerenter: (...)
onpointerleave: (...)
onpointermove: (...)
onpointerout: (...)
onpointerover: (...)
onpointerup: (...)
onprogress: (...)
onratechange: (...)
onreset: (...)
onresize: (...)
onscroll: (...)
onsearch: (...)
onseeked: (...)
onseeking: (...)
onselect: (...)
onselectionchange: (...)
onselectstart: (...)
onstalled: (...)
onsubmit: (...)
onsuspend: (...)
ontimeupdate: (...)
ontoggle: (...)
onvolumechange: (...)
onwaiting: (...)
onwebkitfullscreenchange: (...)
onwebkitfullscreenerror: (...)
onwheel: (...)
outerHTML: "<div class="ng-option" role="option" id="ae295dfb0d66">↵↵            <!---->↵↵            <!--bindings={↵  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]",↵  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"↵}-->↵                <span class="ng-option-label">Gdańsk</span>↵            ↵        </div>"
outerText: "Gdańsk"
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: div
parentNode: div
part: DOMTokenList [value: ""]
prefix: null
previousElementSibling: div#a7b240bd797e.ng-option
previousSibling: div#a7b240bd797e.ng-option
scrollHeight: 31
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 242
shadowRoot: null
slot: ""
spellcheck: true
style: CSSStyleDeclaration {alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: "", …}
tabIndex: -1
tagName: "DIV"
textContent: "↵↵            ↵↵            ↵                Gdańsk↵            ↵        "
title: ""
translate: true
__zone_symbol__clickfalse: [ZoneTask]
__zone_symbol__mouseoverfalse: [ZoneTask]
__proto__: HTMLDivElement
1: div#a73a9e1ddfb0.ng-option
2: div#acb834143a79.ng-option
3: div#aee4c4947524.ng-option
4: div#a7ce7a564daa.ng-option.ng-option-marked
5: div#a5afbfed816d.ng-option
6: div#ae097ef81dc2.ng-option
7: div#a48cdbf7f2da.ng-option
8: div#aa18d929cb28.ng-option
9: div#a90ccbee3869.ng-option
10: div#a90604682f2c.ng-option
11: div#ae68c651855a.ng-option
12: div#a82a56bd88d0.ng-option
13: div#a66361b792e6.ng-option
14: div#af5a67b311ae.ng-option
length: 15
__proto__: Array(0)
Elements:  15
cypress_runner.js:174490 Selector:  [class="ng-option"]`